# NSTextAttachment image not shown in NSTextView (but in UITextView)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

I am having issues getting a `NSTextAttachment` image to work in a `NSTextView` for an OS X application.

The image of the `NSTextAttachment` is just not displayed at all. However, it still seems to be set correctly. Because when copying the contents of the `NSTextView` and pasting it back into e.g. TextEdit.app, the pasted text contains the image correctly.

Here is a minimal playground reproducing the issue:

```
import Cocoa

let img = NSImage(named: "Checked")

let textView = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 254, 64))

let attrstr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test")

let attch = NSTextAttachment()
attch.image = img

attrstr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attch))

textView.textStorage!.setAttributedString(attrstr)

textView
```

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

For iOS, so using UIKit instead of Cocoa, it works perfectly fine:

```
import UIKit

let img = UIImage(named: "Checked")

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 44.0))

let attrstr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test")

let attch = NSTextAttachment()
attch.image = img

attrstr.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attch))

textView.attributedText = attrstr

textView
```

[image]

I am using XCode 7. Both playgrounds can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6699613/nstextattachmentplayground.zip).

Any idea is highly welcome, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var thumbnailImage: NSImage? = // some image
var attachmentCell: NSTextAttachmentCell = NSTextAttachmentCell.initImageCell(thumbnailImage!)
var attachment: NSTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.attachmentCell = attachmentCell
var attrString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString.attributedStringWithAttachment(attachment)
self.textView.textStorage().appendAttributedString(attrString)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly fine! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to provide drag & drop with the image of the cell? By default if I drag it to Finder it creates an empty text file