# How to pull NSImage from NSTextAttachment in NSTextView?

Tags: macos, nsattributedstring, nstextview, nsimage, nstextattachment

Goal is to allow user to add `NSImage`(s) to an `NSAttributedString` in an `NSTextView`, and then reverse the process and extract the image(s). With code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105805/nstextattachment-image-not-shown-in-nstextview-but-in-uitextview), can add image(s) and have them displayed inline.

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes as? [String : AnyObject])

let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
let imageTest = NSImage(named:"sampleImage") as NSImage?
let attachmentCell: NSTextAttachmentCell = NSTextAttachmentCell.init(imageCell: imageTest)
attachment.attachmentCell = attachmentCell
let imageString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
attributedText.append(imageString)
textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedText)
```

Can deconstruct this as far as a legit (non-nil) `NSTextAttachment`, but uncertain how to extract the image.

```
if (textView.textStorage?.containsAttachments ?? false) {
    let runs = textView.textStorage?.attributeRuns
    if runs != nil {
        for run in runs! {
            var r = NSRange()
            let att = run.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &r)
            let z = att[NSAttachmentAttributeName] as? NSTextAttachment
            if z != nil {
                Swift.print(z!)
                // z!.image and z!.contents are both nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any guidance on how to pull the image(s) from this. Thank you.

Comment: I gave a similar solution in Objective-C and iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29152660/extract-uiimage-from-nsattributed-string But I guess it may be applied (maybe with a few modifications for OS X).

Comment: What works in iOS for `UIImage` doesn't work for MacOS and `NSImage`, it seems. `image` is nil and `imageForBounds` returns what looks like a blank document icon.

Comment: Does `z.content` have value? Or is there any property that aren't nil?

Comment: z.content is nil. Answer posted below. Thanks for contributing. In clicking around your link and links from that, somehow fell into the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `NSImage` was created with an `NSTextAttachmentCell`, it must be retrieved from the attachment cell. The key is to cast the cell as `NSCell` and then grab the `image` property. So, replacing the section of code from the original

```
if z != nil {
    let cell = z!.attachmentCell as? NSCell
    if cell != nil {
        let image = cell?.image
    }
}
```